# Show list of taxonomy terms inside a specific taxonomy

Tags: php

I have a "product" custom post type and two taxonomies: categories (tables, chairs, etc) and collections (nameofcollection1, nameofcollection2).

Now, I'm in the product category page, and I would like to show the list of taxonomy collections terms that are not empty and are inside of that category.

For example, if I am in the "table" category, I would show all the collections of tables (not chairs and so on).

I was only able to show all the taxonomies of the product custom post type,

```
        <?php 
        $args=array(
          'public'   => true,
          '_builtin' => false
        );
        $output = 'names'; // or objects
        $operator = 'and';
        $taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 
        if  ($taxonomies) {
          foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
            $terms = get_terms([
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'hide_empty' => true,
        ]);
                foreach ( $terms as $term) {
        ?>

                <li><?php echo $term->name; ?></li>


                 <?php 
                }
            }
        }  
        ?>
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: What do the get_taxonomies() and get_terms() functions do? Have you verified that they are working correctly? Is it your own code or part of a framework or CMS that you're working with? My guess is you have a bug in get_terms() or aren't calling it correctly, but without seeing it, I can't be sure of that, nor can I be any more specific.